# Is there a word for the object or destination of a pilgrimage?

Tags: synonyms

Is there a specific word for the destination of a pilgrimage? (That is, if you go on a pilgrimage to X, X is the _ of the pilgrimage.) I'm looking for a word that has the appropriate spiritual or devotional aspect, not a generic synonym for "destination" or "site" or what-have-you.

Answer (score 5):

Besides being the literal destination for many such pilgrimages, the word ***[Mecca](http://www.onelook.com/?w=mecca&ls=a)*** (sometimes *mecca*) is often used in this way – i.e., metaphorically.

Comment: No, not for a devotional pilgrimage. You could say that the Olympics are a mecca for sports fans; but you couldn't use the word for Walsingham, or Fatima or other pilgrimage sites. Walsingham may be a mecca for Catholicism-junkies, but using "mecca" would be pejorative. (And yes, I'm off to Walsingham next month). Now I have just to think of the right word with the desired devotional/spiritual aspect! That's not easy...

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Fair enough, yet that might depend on how one is using the word _pilgrimage_. Most dictionaries, like [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pilgrimage) or [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/pilgrimage) list two meanings: what you call a "devotional pilgrimage," and a trip made for more sentimental reasons (so, I would say at 2012 trip to the London Olympics could count as a _pilgrimage_). But, you're right: the O.P. specified a "devotional" journey, so I've only answered ½ the question; I look forward to you finishing it :^)

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72442/is-there-a-word-for-the-object-or-destination-of-a-pilgrimage#comment140213_72443), finding the right word to fill in the blank is not easy.

> If you go on a pilgrimage to X, X is the _ of the pilgrimage.

In fact, I think the right word in this context **is** either *destination* or *site*. However, one makes a devotional pilgrimages to a ***shrine***, which may provide the right word for a slightly different sentence.

Note: as in JR's answer, *shrine* can be used in a non-devotional sense too: "His daughter's bedroom was a shrine to Abba."

Comment: Mamma Mia! I do like this answer ([I Do I Do I Do I Do I Do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Do,_I_Do,_I_Do,_I_Do,_I_Do)!). *Shrine* isn't a bad candidate, but my favorite part of all was your example sentence – I think I laughed for a full minute. Even now, I can picture that room in my brain, with the walls covered in posters like [this](http://www.mailce.com/wp-content/uploads/abba.jpg). As you said, this is a tough question; should we send an [SOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOS_(ABBA_song))?

Answer (score 0):

As disappointing as it may seem, the word most commonly used seems to be "end".

[image]

*End* can also refer to the breaking-off of the pilgrimage before it reaches its destination, or the process of arriving at the destination rather than the destination itself. You could also use *goal*, but that can also refer to the spiritual purpose of the pilgrimage and not the final destination. If you want an unambiguous term for the place the pilgrimage is headed, *destination,* as Andrew suggests in his answer, seems to be the right word. If there is an appropriate word for this with devotional connotations, it's not used much.

Comment: "End/Conclusion" can also mean leaving the pilgrimage site after a few days' stay. "End" can also mean "goal", which as you say may be the spiritual purpose. I think there's rather too much ambiguity for the graph to be particularly meaningful (sorry!)